# Finding the value of a variable present in two functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I have two functions each containing a variable besides an $x$.

$$kx-3\quad \text{ and }\quad x^2+k$$

I set them equal to each other, but my algebra is failing me and I can't remember how to solve for $k$

$$kx-3=x^2+k$$

Comment: Were you actually told to equate the two expressions to each other? Or is it something you understood from context not included here? The mere fact that you have two formulas with $x$ and $k$ in it tells us nothing about what is supposed to be done with them. ... Also, see [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1):

Bring the terms involving $k$ together on one side, factor the $k$ out, then divide through:
\begin{align*}
kx - 3 &= x^2 + k \\
kx - k &= x^2 + 3 \\
k(x - 1) &= x^2 + 3 \\
k &= \frac{x^2 + 3}{x - 1}
\end{align*}